# How to get OpenGL to display NV12 texture in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, opengl, transformation, objective-c++, color-space

I have a YUV:420 (aka NV12) frame data, how can I get OpenGL to recognize its format for glTexImage2D() rendering.

I realize that I might have to perform colorspace transformation, but is there a way that I can  tell openGl to command the graphic hardware to perform the colorspace transformation?

Comment: What is your OpenGL hardware target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently verified that OpenGL doest not support NV12 formats. I had to convert my data through hardware acceleration to RGB.